# How to fix error inserting into sql DB using pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I am writing a function which stores tweets pulled with tweepy in Python into a database(SQL server). I have written the following code to insert into the SQL DB

```
 conn = pymssql.connect(host,user,passwd,DB)
cursor = conn.cursor()


def insertTweet(user,text,image):
    query = "INSERT INTO [TWEETS].[dbo].[TWEET_INFO] ] 
    (username,text,image_url,approved)\
    values (user, text, image, 0)"
    cursor.execute(query)
```

This is a very simple function which shouldn't really give an error, but I do get one saying that text is an invalid column name. :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "db_connect.py", line 35, in <module>
insertTweet(user,text,image)
File "db_connect.py", line 19, in insertTweet
cursor.execute(query)
File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 465, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
pymssql.ProgrammingError: (207, b"Invalid column name 'text'.DB-Lib error 
messag
e 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL 
Ser
ver\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: 
Check m
essages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Following is the DB structure :

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
  ,[username]
  ,[text]
  ,[image_url]
  ,[approved]
  FROM [TWEETS].[dbo].[TWEET_INFO]
```

I am not sure how to figure this out. I am able to add by manually running a query in sql studio

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it this way,
Assuming that conn is your connection to the db

```
query = ("INSERT INTO  billed_items(item_name,billed_qty,price,item_bill_series) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)")
c.execute(query,((name),(no),(price),(series))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: that worked! I am not sure why though. I have been using the format I mentioned for a while now.

Comment: Sorry, the above is not useful.